# Leaflet legend not working as intended

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

The legend for one layer in a series is not showing all colors and I cant find out why.

I am confused. I have done a couple of legends by now working on an application and there is this one layer where the legend simply wont behave.

The legend is not picking up any other color but one so all squares are the same color. I have checked and recoded it many times. There has to be something else I'm missing. I have done a jsfiddle with a sample from my data to test and I was surprised to see it do the same thing there.

What could cause this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/dhz4doch/)

Sample of the code:

```
//Get color for Index
function getColorInd(d) {
    return d >= 0.51 ? '#7a0177' : 
    d >= 0.44 && d <= 0.50 ? '#c51b8a' : 
    d >= 0.33 && d <= 0.43 ? '#f768a1' : 
    d >= 0.16 && d <= 0.32 ? '#fbb4b9' :
    '#feebe2';
}

[...]

var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        labels = ['<strong>index</strong>'],
        lower = [0, 0.16, 0.33, 0.44, 0.51],
        upper = [0.15, 0.32, 0.43, 0.50, 0.68];

    for (var i = 0; i < lower.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML += labels.push(
            '<i style="background:' + getColorInd(lower[i] + 1) + '"></i> '+
            lower[i] + '&ndash;' + upper[i]);
    }
    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);

var geojson = L.geoJson(Sample, {
    style: styleInd,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a logical mistake.

You're using `getColorInd(lower[i] + 1)`

replace this by `getColorInd(lower[i])`

means just remove the  **+1** from the `function` and it'd work nicely.

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/4cu28pae/)

Comment: Muzaffar, thank you so much for looking into this. I'm trying to understand the mistake though. I'm new with JavaScript. My other legends are very similar and use +1. What makes this one different?